# Как получить текущий уровень громкости Android?

Tags: java, android

Как получить текущий уровень громкости Android? help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно получить так:

```
 AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
 int volume_level= am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```